# Scedule Event Mysql not accepting syntax BEGIN END

Tags: mysql, sql, events, syntax, mysql-workbench

I must have done something really stupid, but the following is correct:

```
CREATE EVENT delete_old
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
COMMENT 'Clears old cache data from the DB.'
DO
DELETE FROM summoners 
WHERE `date` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Where the next bit seems to throw a syntax error on the last 2 lines:

```
CREATE EVENT delete_old
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
COMMENT 'Clears old cache data from the DB.'
DO BEGIN
DELETE FROM summoners 
WHERE `date` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);
END;
```

The syntax to my knowledge is correct, however MySQL Workbench does not agree. I intend to do multiple tables inside the BEGIN - END section, that is why i need it.

I hope someone can figure out what goes wrong here, i am at a loss.
Thanks in advance,
Smiley

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change the `DELIMITER` to something that doesn't appear in your event body.

I just tried it (MySQL Workbench 6.0.6, MySQL 5.6) and it works fine. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Both comments are clear and correct. I do not recall doing this for oracle sql things however. But this is perfect, thanks!

Comment: It's not uncommon to change the delimiter to handle the ambiguity when semicolon can occur inside the body of a trigger/procedure/event. I know PostgreSQL and Firebird also need to use this technique, for example.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `;` in body breaks your command in the middle. Use different delimiter.

```
DELIMITER | 

CREATE EVENT delete_old
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
COMMENT 'Clears old cache data from the DB.'
DO BEGIN
DELETE FROM summoners 
WHERE `date` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);
END;

| DELIMITER ;
```